# Issue with folder permission

Tags: command-line, permissions, root

I created a bunch of files using the terminal. The file was assigned to the root and I am not able to edit them. Help! What am I missing? New to Ubuntu.

Comment: **How** did you create them? [Edit] your question to show us the command(s) you used.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
sudo chown $USER [filenames]
```

Note: `$USER` is literal, replace `[filenames]` with one or many file names or globs, for example:

```
sudo chown $USER *.md
```

Answer (score 0):

The is necessary to change the owner of the files to your user:

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER file file file ....
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to either change the permissions of those files, or change the owner.
To change the permissions use `chmod`, and to change the owner use `chown`

As a quick and dirty fix try `sudo chmod 777 <filename>`.

Using permission `777` is a bad idea as it gives every permission to every user.

Comment: Why do you suggest "a bad idea"?

Comment: Because between all the option, it's the only one that is certain to work. The other answers suggest `chown $USER` or something along those lines, but if the file has some strange permissions it would still not me accessible.

Comment: To clarify, if the OP wants a better solution, he should post more information about his problem, such as the output of `ls -l`

Comment: I was not criticising the approach with `chmod` but the suggestion of 777.